# how to kill jquery functions if they have already been executed

Tags: jquery, function, tabs, kill

- Using tabs users can click around a tabbed interface
- On each tab
  results are called and display within a visible `div` the rest are
  hidden When a user clicks a tab, it call results for that tab
- I have multiple sets of results per tab each calling functions that would be required if only one set was used (This is a possibility)
- When multiple sets are called my script calls the same functions over and over - for each set

How do I stop subsequent functions from
   reloading once they have already run for the first time on that tab?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery UI tabs implementation, or another implementation?

Comment: no. I'm replacing a div with content from another div using onclick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite common to use a boolean data attribute to indicate whether or not something has already been "filled" by a request. For example:

```
$("#foo").on("click", function () {
    if(!$(this).data("loaded")) {
        $(this).load("foo.html", function () {
            $(this).data("loaded", true);
        }
    }
});
```

If you want a more specific answer, I would suggest that you provide more detail in your question.

Comment: Thats not a bad answer for a vague question. Thanks, I'll give that a try.